# how to change the products view from list to grid view in homepage of magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I am using the mapple theme for magento i have used this code to show product on home page

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="all_products" products_count="10"template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

it will show product as list on home page I want to change this view into grid. so anyone can help me, I am new to magento. thanks in advance for help.

Comment: share the code for new_grid.phtml, as it may not be possible from widget

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is, to copy the template, remove all the list code and especially the `if()` around, so only the grid is left.

Comment: I am glad that you gave me the solution of this problem i have search for this problem and finally find the solution with this code {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change grid to list like

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="all_products" products_count="10"template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml"}}
```

will work like a charm :)