# Change list view to grid view on Magento home page

Tags: featured-product

I am using gala giftshop theme and trying to display my products on home page in grid view.
Here is the content we are referring to display my products.

```
{{widget type="dynamicproducts/dynamicproducts" order_by="name asc" featured_choose="em_featured"  column_count="4"  frontend_title="Featured Products" thumbnail_width="215" thumbnail_height="215" show_product_name="true" show_thumbnail="true" show_description="false" show_price="true" show_reviews="false" show_addtocart="true" show_addto="false" show_label="true" choose_template="custom_template" custom_theme="em_sale_products/sale_home.phtml"}}
```

In above code choose-template="custom_template" refers to the `featured_grid.phtml`.

In catalog also I enabled the grid view as default.

Comment: I thinks its an premium theme try asking the support team your question will be closed here because it is about third party theme.

Comment: @dh47: I don't think this is the only theme related question. Because if i would go for displaying the products in grid view there will be some code to display that.

Comment: Yes may be ok [See this answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30763/how-to-change-the-products-view-from-list-to-grid-view-in-homepage-of-magento).

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
This worked for me.
**choose_template="em_featured_products/featured_custom.phtml**

Comment: Can you explain little more??

Comment: Instead of putting {{choose_template="custom_template"}} i put  {{choose_template="em_featured_products/featured_custom.phtml}}.. so, it is now showing featured product in grid view as i already mentioned featured_custom.phtml refers to featured_grid.phtml.